# how to bind projects without opening visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, powershell, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to update source from another TFS source control and I written a powershell script to get latest and unbind from the original source control.  now I am trying take this code and port it into another source control and bind it to the source control.  I don't want to have to open Visual Studio to set the bindings...I would like to be able to run the script to update binding and checkin the new code.  Is there any way to do this outside of Visual Studio?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding information is just text in the solution file and XML values in the project file.  When we had to change domains (company split) we wrote scripts to modify the source control info in all of our SLN files.  That's pretty easy.  The project files for the most part don't need to change if they are already set to `SAK` (should already know).

Comment: Thanks for making me think about how I need to process the files.  I ended up not unbinding anything from the project or solution files.  I just had to edit/change the solution file where SccTeamFoundationServer = http://ServerSource:8080/tfs/defaultcollection  to SccTeamFoundationServer = http://ServerTarget:8080/tfs/defaultcollection